# Problem with a book I just started studying today

Tags: geometry, logic

I'm only through the first chapter but I'm thinking maybe I should get a different book. It seems like this text is written in such a way that you have to think exactly like the author to understand where he's coming from. This is especially true for the problem sets. I am finding I have to read certain sections twice before I get it. I find that very frustrating. Should I dump the book and try another author or should I stick it out for a few more chapters? The material is not all that hard, just basic logic.

Comment: Which book is it?

Comment: I don't know what the subject is but I know that many subjects I am interested in would take many days and readings before I would expect to understand clearly. Getting frustrated after one day with a book seems a little premature.

Comment: What is the **mathematical** problem here? Given the information you have provided, your book could be about roller-skating!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Can you at least tell us what level of math you are studying, and what the name/author of your book is?

Comment: Having only to read it twice is no reason to get frustrated. Twice often isn't enough for more advanced stuff.

Comment: Oh, great, I just asked a question about a book.  I suppose I will get negative points too.

Answer (score 3):

It is often a good strategy to look at ***multiple*** books simultaneously. If you don't get the presentation of the material in one of them you can always check the other.

In instances where it seems as if the book is written more for you to follow the author and not for the author to explain his/her perspective to you in detail, it can also be helpful to pick a book which covers the same material in a very basic manner, which might fill in the gaps in your knowledge necessary to understand the more difficult presentation of the material.